# Command line commands in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a command that I use in the command line to replace certain lower case characters with upper case, which works fine:

```
cat file | sed -e 's/^ g/G /;s/^ h/H /;s/^ n/N /;s/^ b/B /' > newfile
```

Is there a way I can write this into a shell script and call

> bash uppercase.sh file

instead of copy and pasting into the command line every time?

Currently when I copy and paste the command into a shell script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -e 's/^ g/G /;s/^ h/H /;s/^ n/N /;s/^ b/B /'
```

The terminal becomes unresponsive

Comment: `sed` is just waiting for input. Since you didn’t supply a filename it’s reading STDIN, and since you, I assume, aren’t piping anything to the script it just waits (Ctrl+d should close it). How do you usually run the `sed` command (they one you posted would give the exact same behaviour)?

Comment: I would type cat file | sed ....> newfile. Would cat file | bash uppercase.sh file > newfile work

Comment: sorry, the colons are just from the command line, will edit them out now

Comment: Yes, it should work as intended.

Comment: Works now! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: (Note that `uppercase.sh < file > newfile` is considered more ‘correct’ than using `cat` and `|`. A minor difference, but it lets you into the Cool Hackers Club™.)

Answer (score 0):

try appending '$1' to the sed command in the script, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -e 's/^ g/G /;s/^ h/H /;s/^ n/N /;s/^ b/B /' $1
```

Then, run it like this:

```
bash uppercase.sh file
```

Comment: To make the script more useful and allow multiple files to be given as arguments, write it as `sed -e ... "$@"`

Comment: But don't try running it as `bash uppercase.sh 'this is a file'` since you don't quote `$1`.

Comment: Don't forget to quote your variables, [weird bugs may occur](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Answer (score -1):

create bash file uppercase.sh with:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    sed -e 's/^ g/G /;s/^ h/H /;s/^ n/N /;s/^ b/B /' $1 > newfile
```

use:  uppercase.sh  file

Comment: Quote your variables!

Answer (score -1):

If writing to a script, use the `$1` argument as mentioned above, but if you are including the "shebang" line (`#!/bin/bash`) and setting the permissions correctly (e.g., `chmod u+x uppercase.sh`) then you shouldn't *need* to specify the `bash` on the command line. It doesn't hurt, but it's superfluous. You could just use

```
uppercase.sh old > new
```

If your PATH isn't set to find it, you will need to specify pathing info such as a leading `./`, but if it's in a `bin` folder in your PATH it will work fine.

If you just want it for convenience you could make an alias.

```
$: alias capit='sed -E "s/^( [ghnb])/\U&/"'
```

This makes the short name `capit` a synonym that gets replaced when parsed with `sed -E "s/^( [ghnb])/\U&/"`, but you'd need to put the alias command in your profile so that it would reload on each login, of it would just go away when you log out.

I made a quick test file.

```
$: cat x
hi
 hello
going?
 gone.
never?
 nope.
baloney!
 bye!
and
other
 stuff
 uncapitalized.
```

and ran the alias against it.

```
$: capit x > y
$: cat y
hi
 Hello
going?
 Gone.
never?
 Nope.
baloney!
 Bye!
and
other
 stuff
 uncapitalized.
```

If you want it as a script, the methods above work well, but you might still want the regex. It just remembers the first letter in a specified list after a space at the beginning of a line (the `(...)`) using a character class (the `[...]`), and `\U` uppercases `&` (what it remembered).

Comment: I noticed I was downvoted and realized I hadn't answered the question *asked*. Even if I was helpful and useful, it wasn't what was requested. I edited my post, but leave the downvote so people who see it remember to `1)` ask what they want, instead of what they think should be the answer, and `2)` answer the QUESTION, even if you have other useful (if unrelated) suggestions. The voting system isn't a popularity contest, it's a training tool. Use it accordingly, as (I assume) was done here.

Comment: I am assuming the corrections with $1 other folk already provided.

Comment: "If writing to a script, use the $1 argument as mentioned above, ..."